# HttpPost Delete MVC for Composite Keys

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I have a table with three columns with first two formulating the **composite key**

1. SrcSys (CompositeKey Part I)
2. CustId (CompositeKey Part II)
3. CustNm

I am new to ASP & starting with MVC Core.

The following code for get method works well:

```
    public async Task<IActionResult> Delete(string _SrcSys, string _CustId)
    {
        if (_SrcSys == null || _CustId == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }
        var customer = await _context.Customers.SingleOrDefaultAsync(Cust => Cust.SrcSys == _SrcSys && Cust.CustId == _CustId);
        if (customer == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }
        return View(customer);
    }
```

The relevant code of Delete.cshtml is:

```
@model RiskDotNet.Models.Customer

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Delete";
}

@*<h2>Delete</h2>*@
<br />
<hr />
<dl class="dl-horizontal">
    <dt>
        Src Sys
    </dt>
    <dd>
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.SrcSys)
    </dd>
    <dt>
        Cust ID
    </dt>
    <dd>
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.CustId)
    </dd>
    <dt>
        Customer
    </dt>
    <dd>
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.CustNm)
    </dd>
</dl>

<form asp-action="Delete">
    <div class="form-actions no-color">
        <input type="submit" value="Delete" class="btn btn-default" />
        <p />
        <p />
        <input type="submit" value="Cancel" class="btn btn-default" a asp-action="Index">
    </div>
</form>
```

All the three fields are appearing on the page.

In respect of HttpPost what would be a reasonable piece of code?

Answer (score 1):

You need to put the SrcSys and CustId in the form so they can be passed to the backend on the submit.

You can just put this in the form part:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.SrcSys)
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.CustId)
```

These properties wont be displayed but they will be submitted.

**Sidenote**

Dont use Html helpers ( @Html.DisplayFor, @Html.HiddenFor..) they are the old way of doing things. 
Use tag helpers that came with MVC Core:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/tag-helpers/intro

Comment: Thanks for all your suggestions but what would be the HttpPost code for the same?

Answer (score 1):

I resolved the problem myself:
Updated HttpPost:

```
[HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult> DeletePost(Customer customer)
{
    try
    {
        _context.Entry(customer).State = EntityState.Deleted;
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Delete", new { ss = customer.SrcSys, ci = customer.CustId });
    }
}
```

and Updated Delete.cshtml:

```
@model RiskDotNet.Models.Customer

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Delete";
}

<hr />
<dl class="dl-horizontal">
    <dt>
        Src Sys
    </dt>
    <dd>
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.SrcSys)
    </dd>
    <dt>
        Cust ID
    </dt>
    <dd>
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.CustId)
    </dd>
    <dt>
        Customer
    </dt>
    <dd>
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.CustNm)
    </dd>
</dl>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.SrcSys)
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.CustId)

    <form asp-action="Delete">
        <div class="form-actions no-color">
            <input type="submit" value="Delete" class="btn btn-default" />
            <p />
            <p />
            <input type="submit" value="Cancel" class="btn btn-default" a asp-action="Index">
        </div>
    </form>
}
```

Did the job!!!
:-)